# Micropython: _thread module imported but not showing methods

Tags: python, pycharm, cpython, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Using PyCharm Community Edition 2023.3.2 with Micropython 1.4.3-2023.3 installed and enabled in PyCharm, I want to utilize the 2-core multithreading on a Raspberry Pi Pico W using the experimental "_thread" library. When I try to use a method from the module, PyCharm says there is no reference to the method, [even though it can find _thread.pyi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsAUQ.png)

When I dot search for any available methods, [only 4 dunder methods show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfwch.png)

I think it's just PyCharm's referencing that is the problem, and the Pico W would still execute the code, but it would be nice to have some reference to double-check check what I'm doing is in line with the syntax.

I have tried repairing the IDE up to invalidating the caches and restarting. I have also redownloaded and reinstalled the same Micropython version on 2 different devices with the same version of PyCharm. I don't know any further steps for troubleshooting this.